# Single column contain multiple delimiter

Tags: talend

I have a below requirement, can you please help on this.

| Emp_id | Emp_name | Salary | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rahul | 1000 | 10,MI,IN |
| 3 | Rama | 2000 | 20,VIO,US |

I have above data which is comma separated file and field separator is “,”.
But the problem is Address column has multiple comma in same column.
When I am trying to read getting only below output.

```
1 , Rahul , 1000 , 10
3 , Rama , 2000 , 20
```

I want output like below.

```
1 , Rahul , 1000 , 10,MI,IN
3 , Rama , 2000 , 20,VIO,US
```

Comment: Your CSV is broken. Fields that contain commas must be enclosed in quotes. See [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2).

Answer (score 0):

You should try with a tFileInputRegex (or tExtractRegexField) with 4 fields in schema output, using this regex

```
"^([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),(.+)$"
```

See https://regex101.com/r/izd0Wu/1/